# Refactor left recursion infinite loop

Tags: python, recursion, math, formula, recurrence

When you trying to implement this formula

[image]

in a straightforward manner using this code

```
def P(n, p, limit):
    if n == limit:
        return 1

    if n == -limit:
        return 0

    return p*P(n+1, p, limit) + (1-p)*P(n-1, p, limit)
```

you will definitely end up with this error.

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

So how to properly implement such class of problems using code? Is there a technique used to refactor this and get a solution? Or the only thing is to solve that mathematically first and only then feed into computation?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: memoization doesn't solve infinite recursion; it merely removes redundancy.

Comment: @Prune oops thanks for the catch, don't know why I thought memoization would have even helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on `@Prune`'s suggestions, this recurrence can be written as **two** other recurrences, by moving either of the terms on the RHS to LHS:

> [image]

These are non-cyclic because each term only depends on terms either before **or** after it, not both.

---

However, they cannot be solved independently, because that requires knowledge of P<sub>1-l</sub> and P<sub>l-1</sub>, where `l = limit`.

Making some substitutions for convenience:

[image]

Note that, since the relations only contain *linear* terms (no e.g. P<sub>n</sub> × P<sub>n-1</sub> etc.), all terms in their expansions will also be linear in the variables `x, y`:

[image]

These newly introduced coefficients also obey similar recurrence relations:

[image]

Their boundary conditions are:

[image]

Now that the boundary conditions are known, the coefficients can be computed iteratively. It only remains to equate the expressions for P<sub>1-l</sub> and P<sub>l-1</sub> from both recurrences:

[image]

Solving this pair of simultaneous equations gives P<sub>1-l</sub> and P<sub>l-1</sub>, from which any P<sub>n</sub> can be calculated (using the coefficients computed earlier):

> [image]

---

**Update**: sample Python implementation

```
# solve a recurrence of the form
# Tn = c1 * Tn-1 + c2 * Tn-2, n >= 0
def solve_recurrence(c1, c2, t1, t2, n):
    if n <= 0: return t2
    if n == 1: return t1
    a, b = t2, t1
    for i in range(1, n):
        a, b = b, c1 * b + c2 * a
    return b

# solve the loop recurrence
def solve_loop(limit, p, n):
    assert(limit > 0 and abs(n) <= limit)
    assert(p > 0 and p < 1)

    # corner cases
    if n == -limit: return 0
    if n ==  limit: return 1

    # constants
    a, c = 1 / p, 1 / (1 - p)
    b, d = 1 - a, 1 - c

    # coefficients at 2l - 1
    e = 2 * limit - 1
    l = solve_recurrence(a, b, 1, 0, e)
    m = solve_recurrence(a, b, 0, 0, e)
    s = solve_recurrence(c, d, 1, 0, e)
    t = solve_recurrence(c, d, 0, 1, e)
    # note that m can just be 0 but was left in for generality

    # solving the simultaneous equations
    # to get P at 1 - l and l - 1
    x = (s * m + t) / (1 - s * l)
    y = (l * t + m) / (1 - l * s)

    # iterate from the closest side to improve precision
    if n < 0:
        return solve_recurrence(a, b, x, 0, limit + n)
    else:
        return solve_recurrence(c, d, y, 1, limit - n)
```

Experimental results for `limit = 10, p = 0.1`:

```
n       | P(n)            abs. error
========================================
-10     | 0.0000000E+00   --
-9      | 6.5802107E-19   0.0000000E+00
-8      | 6.5802107E-18   1.7995889E-30
-7      | 5.9879917E-17   1.7995889E-29
-6      | 5.3957728E-16   5.0003921E-28
-5      | 4.8568535E-15   8.1994202E-27
-4      | 4.3712339E-14   8.9993252E-27
-3      | 3.9341171E-13   5.1002066E-25
-2      | 3.5407061E-12   5.9938283E-25
-1      | 3.1866355E-11   5.9339980E-18
 0      | 2.8679726E-10   5.3406100E-17
 1      | 2.5811749E-09   3.3000371E-21
 2      | 2.3230573E-08   2.6999175E-20
 3      | 2.0907516E-07   2.2999591E-19
 4      | 1.8816764E-06   7.9981086E-19
 5      | 1.6935088E-05   1.9989978E-18
 6      | 1.5241579E-04   3.5000757E-16
 7      | 1.3717421E-03   1.5998487E-15
 8      | 1.2345679E-02   3.2000444E-14
 9      | 1.1111111E-01   6.9999562E-14
 10     | 1.0000000E+00   --
```

---

Notes:

- It is clear from the code and equations that the recurrence limits / boundary conditions can be arbitrary.
- Numerical precision can be improved with summation techniques such as Kahan-Neumaier.
- There also exists an alternative explicit formula for the iterative method used in `solve_recurrence`, which may produce more accurate results if used in conjunction with library functions.

Comment: I'm not sure I get the premise: once you have (i), you can compute everything, as long as you fix P1 and P2, no?

Comment: @BlackBear what do you mean by `P1, P2`? The boundary conditions that OP has given? The latter are not adjacent terms but at the opposite ends of the recurrence range.

Comment: Ah, now I understand, the boundary conditions are on the first and the last element, not on the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion depends on breaking the problem into pieces, each of which is closer to a base case.  The formula you give is infinite because it depends on series terms that are equally undefined.  A simple-looking mathematical notation is no guarantee of computability.

In this case, you have to rewrite the recursion relation in non-circular terms.  You can still use recursion, but there has to be a definite end.  In the given formula, P[n] depends on P[n+1] and P[n-1], *each* of which depends directly upon P[n].  This is algorithmically circular.

You need to extract the algorithm from the base cases, starting from the ends and working your way in.  One of the unfortunate results of this recursion relation is that you have to solve the entire range [-limit, limit] in order to get the value for your desired position.  The base-case values ripple from the ends to wherever you have your viewpoint.

There is no tool to symbolically unravel this for you.  Most of all, note that your base cases do not appear in the equation.  Even if you provided those as additional equations, deriving the exponential series from this relationship  is beyond the analysis capabilities of today's solvers.

Comment: I perfectly understand this explanation and that's what my question is implying? Is there something (e.g. symbolic computation) that can tackle this kind of issues?

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution using symbolic computation.

```
class X(object):
    """Representing unknown value which will be resolved in future"""
    def __init__(self, value=1.0):
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other):
        cls = self.__class__
        return cls(value=self.value+other.value)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        cls = self.__class__
        return cls(value=self.value-other.value)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        cls = self.__class__
        if isinstance(other, cls):
            return cls(value=self.value*other.value)
        elif isinstance(other, numbers.Real):
            return cls(value=self.value*other)
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'Cannot multiply with type {type(other)}')

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)
```

Instead of obtaining numeric results immediately we rely on the fact that resulting value will be expressed in some way as

[image: eq1]

and each intermediate term will be represented as

[image: eq2]

That's why we define add/subtract/multiplicate operations for our object.

So having a representation of such a symbol in a code we can solve this equation with an approach similar to accepted answer (we go from both `-limit` and `limit` sides and express other terms as yet unknown product). When reaching base point (`0` state) we would have ratio of our probability and numeric value for that ratio which allows us to calculate the result easily

```
_memory = []
def fill_memory(n):
    global _memory
    _memory = [(0, X(1))]*(2*n+1)
    _memory[-n] = (0, X(0))
    _memory[n] = (1, X(0))


def resolve(n, p):
    q = 1-p
    for i in reversed(range(n)):
        # resolve from right to center
        prob_next = _memory[i+1]
        prob_prev = _memory[i-i]
        _memory[i] = (
            q*prob_prev[0] + p*prob_next[0],
            q*prob_prev[1] + p*prob_next[1],
        )

        # resolve from left to center
        prob_prev = _memory[-i-1]
        prob_next = _memory[-i+1]
        _memory[-i] = (
            q*prob_prev[0] + p*prob_next[0],
            q*prob_prev[1] + p*prob_next[1],
        )

    # calculate base probability
    solution = _memory[0]
    coef = (X(value=1) - solution[1]).value
    p0 = solution[0] / coef
    return p0
```

I have obtained correct and very precise results with this approach (I'm using `p=0.6` and `N=4` (limit))

```
def main():
    N = 4
    p = 0.6
    fill_memory(N)
    p0 = resolve(N, p)
    print(f'Probability for N={N} steps is {p0*100:.4}%')
    for i in range(2*N+1):
        print(i-N, '->', _memory[i-N])
```

> ```
> 4 - 83.505%
> 3 - 77.143%
> 2 - 69.231%
> 1 - 60.0%
> ```

As you can see it's the same result as when resolving it mathematically.